# Endless rain in a cave

Tags: hard-science, geology

I am currently designing an extensive big volcanic cave system located underneath a glacier, which contains a phenomenon of underground rain. The nearby volcano is still active, and heats the ice year round. The glacial meltwater runs down through the fractured basalt and creates endless 'rain' inside the cave. I only just realised it would more be like small waterfalls instead of evenly dispersed droplets due to the basalt being fractured as to being porous. How can I still cause this endless rain and limit erosion to a minimum?

Comment: I don't have hard-science numbers or anything, so not an answer, but if the water runoff goes into a pond, that is heated somewhat by the geothermal activity, you'll get steam (non-scalding), which can condense on the colder ceiling, causing it to rain.

Comment: How on earth has the glacier not been exhausted?  Over geologic time, a volcano is going to melt the glacier much more quickly than it can be replenished.

Comment: That is a key element of the story. One day, the endless rain stops, blah blah blah, apocalypse, etc

Answer (score 3):

## Ice

Ice is your friend.  Keep the rock itself cold, cold enough to freeze water.  Keep the water a little warmer than that.  The line of balance between frozen water and liquid, assuming temperatures remain consistent, will keep a layer of ice on the rock.  The water won't erode the rock, it'll just strip some ice and freeze in its place.  It'd be dependent on where the volcano's working and where the meltwater flows, obviously.

Citations:

- [Glacial ice protects plateau edge from erosion from nearby river over geologic time](https://www.washington.edu/news/2008/10/09/preserved-by-ice-glacial-dams-helped-prevent-erosion-of-tibetan-plateau-2/)
- [Glacial Blankets Can Prevent Mountains From Eroding](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2010/09/glacial-blankets-can-protect-mountains-erosion) *Science*, Phil Berardelli, September 2010
- [Study on the facilities and procedures for meltwater erosion of thawed soil](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2095633915301106), *International Soil and Water Conservation Research*, Yunyun Ban, June 2016

Comment: Please note the hard-science tag

Comment: Citations added, but this doesn't require formulae.

Comment: Your big problem is if this water infiltration is constant it will heat the area up to match it. that is a LOT of heat coming inot the system if it is constant.